# Cross reference not able to find table, while example table is working

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I am trying to reference a table.
However I get the error:
Reference `table:PortfolioSummary' on page 7 undefined

I used an example table to see if that works, and it works.
The example table and the table I need are both in the same folder.

Example table is:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{\label{table:widgets}An example table.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\\\hline
Item & Quantity \\\hline
Candles & 4 \\
Fork handles & ? 
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

And the table I need to reference is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{\label{table:PortfolioSummary}Portfolio Summary}
some text of table
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}

table information

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

In my reference, I wrote the following code, to test both:

```
As we can see in table~\ref{table:widgets}  ~\ref{table:PortfolioSummary}
```

The output is: As we can see in table 1 ??
meaning the second reference does not work but the first one does.
Does someone have a clue what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

edit: when I post the table in another file in the document, the reference does work. However not when I use in the one I'm trying to use it in, it doesn't.

main code:

```
\tableofcontents

\include{01_Chapters/01_Introduction}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\include{01_Chapters/02_LitteratureReview}
\include{01_Chapters/03_Data}
\include{01_Chapters/04_Methodology}
\include{01_Chapters/05_results}
\endgroup
\newpage
```

It works when the table is in introduction but not in results

code of results:

```
\section{Results}
\input{03_Tables/01_Descriptive_Statistics}
\subsection{Descriptive statistics}


As we can see in table~\ref{table:widgets}  ~\ref{table:PortfolioSummary}
```

I don't know what the problem is then...

Comment: did you run latex again to resolve the cross reference? Otherwise please always give a complete small document that shows the problem, we can not debug disconnected fragments

Comment: Yes I have rerun latex multiple times, this did not resolve the issue. Is there a way to upload my overleaf file?

Comment: No you should be able to make a small complete 1-pag document that shows the problem. Start from a copy of your document delete everything you can delete apart from one table and a bad `\ref` then delete any packages not used in the example, checking at each stage the problem still shows. Post the resulting file as a code block in your question

Comment: oh sorry, no need. You have `\let\clearpage\relax`  !!!! That completely breaks latex, no cross referencing can work if you do that.

Comment: Thank you for helping. That did indeed solve the problem!

Answer (score 4):

`\let\clearpage\relax`  Completely breaks LaTeX. Cross referencing will fail, as you show, and it can also easily throw LaTeX into an infinite loop as LaTeX will issue `\clearpage` at points to flush out floats such as figures, and as this has been disabled, the stack of floats will never change.

If the intention is to avoid page breaking, use `\input` not `\include`.